# OpenLayers load WFS vector layer: how to check whether all features are returned from server?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, request, loading

My app takes several seconds to return all features of a WFS layer from server, I am wondering whether there is a way to check whether all features are returned in coding, so that we can add a loading-mask...

In other words, how do you check whether a WFS request is successful or not?

**Code sample:**

```js
var newEventLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector
(
    'test'
    , { "strategies":
            [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()
            , new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({ "force": true })
            ]
        , "protocol": new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS(
        {   "version": '1.0.0'
            , "srsName": 'EPSG:4326'
            , "url": '/geoserver/ows?service=WFS'
            , "featureType": 'XXX'
            , "featureNS": 'XXXX'
            , "geometryName": 'GEOM'
        })
    }
);

map.addLayer(newEventLayer);
```

Comment: Please provide more information, a bit of code would be nice and are you using OpenLayers.Format.WFS or OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS?

Comment: What should happen is the server will return some sort of response depending on the success or failure of the request, so you should wait for that. of course, the server could stop responding for some reason, in which case you should have some sort of reasonable timeout in your client that displays a "server not responding" type message.

Comment: I am using OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.

Comment: @MerseyViking I understand server will return some info no matter success or failure. but i don't know how to 'monitor' this response with the use of OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming your are using `OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS`, then you have something like this and you can provide a callback when you call the read operation on the protocol:

The call back has an [`OpenLayers.Protocol.Response`](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Protocol-js.html#OpenLayers.Protocol.Response.OpenLayers.Protocol.Response) object. This object has an `error` property that will let you know of any errors.

```js
    var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        url: xxx
        featurePrefix: xxx
        featureType: xxx
        featureNS: xxx
        geometryName: xxx
//        defaultFilter: searchFilter,
        srsName: xxx
    });

    var response = protocol.read({
        maxFeatures: 100,
        callback: _CallBack
    });

   function _CallBack (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        console.log(resp.error);
    });
```

[image]

## Update

The problem with supplying the protocol in the layer constructor is that you don't get the chance to call `.read()` yourself and the opportunity to provide your own callback to monitor the response because the layer does it for you.

So if you want to monitor the results you're going to have to create the layer and protocol separate so you can call the `.read()` whenever you click the  "search" button for example. Then when you get the results you add those features to the layer `newEventLayer.addFeatures(resp.features);`

```js
var newEventLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('test');
map.addLayer(newEventLayer);
var protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    version: "1.1.0",
    url: xxx,
    featurePrefix: xxx,
    featureType: xxx,
    featureNS: xxx,
    geometryName: xxx,
    defaultFilter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
        filters: getMyFilter()
    }),
    srsName: xxx
});

var response = protocol.read({
    maxFeatures: 100,
    callback: _CallBack
});

function _CallBack (resp) {
    newEventLayer.addFeatures(resp.features);
});
```

## Update 2

Try this if `_callBack` is not called:

```js
var _CallBack = function (resp) {
    newEventLayer.addFeatures(resp.features);
});
var response = protocol.read({
    maxFeatures: 100,
    callback: _CallBack
});
```

## Filter Strategy

You are right, i have removed the strategy from the layer constructor. You are going to have to specify your [filter separately](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/765/openlayers-filter-ogc-xml-or-cql) or in the protocol constructor as I have it above. But you're going to have build a search filter anyway if you want to search your WFS service by attributes, date/time, etc. Or did you only want to rely on the BBox Strategy (give me EVERYTHING in the BBOX)? If so then just set up a filter for that and call the `protocol.read()` on the map extentchange event. After all, that's all the strategy does. But that's seperate question which I, or others can help you with.

Comment: thanks very much! one further question, as you see, in the code sample, this layer request has strategy & protocol parameters, and I assume internally it will call protocol.read in order to get features; in your answer, I need to explicitly call protocol.read() again in order to get the response. Does this mean this function is called twice? if this is the case, how can I avoid one of them, which means, we only need call it once and we want to have its callBack function enabled with it. thanks again!

Comment: It will not be called twice because you will not pass the protocol object you create to the layer's constructor. You will call protocol.read(), get results, then add the results.features to your layer.

Comment: hmmm.. not quite work yet... callBack func is not called; and, I am not sure whether the protocol uses layer strategy or not, because initially they don't have any relationship..

Comment: @Simon Check my update 2.

Comment: thanks again! I do use attribute filter though. Am still looking for a way to make separate protocol instance and filter instance work together...

Comment: no problem... open up another question, we'll get a working example running for you. Just make sure you include snippets of the code you have already so we can work off of.

Comment: I created a new question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21740/openlayers-wfs-protocol-work-with-filters-if-the-protocol-is-defined-out-of-lay appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do a loading mask (without checking for errors) you can use the 'loadend' event:

```
layer.events.register('loadend', olLayer, function () {

  turn off your loading mask
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check this with some programatical way:

in extjs:

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
         url : 'wmsServerAdress',
                  method: 'POST',
                  params :{....},
                  success: function ( result, request ) {
                      var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
                      //do something
               },
                  failure: function ( result, request ) {
                   var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
                   //do something
               }
       });
```

in jquery:

```
 $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: 'wmsServerAdress',  
        dataType: 'text',  
        success: function(result){//doSomething},   
        error: function(data) {//doSomething);} 
    });
```

and with this codes you can get the result of whether your wms request have loaded or not.

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I am looking for.