# OpenLayers, zoom to vector layer extent

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

It seems quite simple thing to me, but I get an error.

## map declaration

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', {...
projection : _projObj.mercator,
displayProjection : _projObj.wgs84
}
```

## layer declaration

```
uses_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("US Layer", {
    strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    projection : _projObj.wgs84,
    visibility : true,
    protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version : '1.0.0',
        url : '[...]wfs.map&service=WFS',
        featureType : USType
    })
});
```

## center to layer extent

After the layer gets successfully loaded, I want to zoom to the vector layer extent:

```
map.zoomToExtent(uses_layer.getDataExtent());
```

and I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCenterLonLat' of null
OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Class.zoomToExtentOpenLayers.js:512
addSelectedLayermap.js:87
(anonymous function)46.105.19.68:36
f.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.2.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i
```

When I pass the same commands from JS debug command line (embedded in Chrome), the map get zoomed correctly; nonetheless,

```
uses_layer.getDataExtent();
```

from command line, gives me

```
bottom: 5134852.1720288
centerLonLat: null
left: 1744085.9879363
right: 1787837.9987162
top: 5150209.4139235
```

Now, `centerLonLat` is `null`, but in the [docs](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.zoomToExtent) it is said that the only reqested value is a bound with coordinates array, that IMHO fits with the `uses_layer.getDataExtent();` request.

Any hint?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that your layer hasn't finished downloading when you call getDataExtent()? while in the debugger it is going more slowly and the download has finished.

This previous question [OpenLayers load WFS vector layer: how to check whether all features are returned from server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21652/openlayers-load-wfs-vector-layer-how-to-check-whether-all-features-are-returned) should help.

Comment: Thanks, issues solved. I've implemented the load check as follows: `uses_layer.events.register('loadend', uses_layer, function(evt){map.zoomToExtent(uses_layer.getDataExtent())})`