# Geoserver Exception Handling

Tags: geoserver

I'm implementing an application that uses GeoServer deployed on apache tomcat. I would like to know if there is a way to handle an error case, such as when GeoServer is hung. For example, I'd like to display a message to user or something like that on client side.

I've been told that :

```
If GeoServer hangs, you will receive no answer. You should set a read   
time out for your GeoServer HTTP requests. After the timeout, you can   
send back whatever you want.
```

but since I'm pretty beginner at these stuff, I've no idea how to do that. would anyone please explain me more how to set a readtime out for your GeoServer HTTP requests ??

**EDIT: 
Can I convert the configuration in proxyhost to message displays to the user ?**

Comment: this is an issue for your client application not GeoServer (which clearly can't reply).

Comment: Thanks! but how my client application would handle it? do you have a simple code to explain me please?

Comment: which client are you using?

Comment: apache tomcat to serve geoserver, and apache httpd to sere my applicatopn

Comment: these are both servers - you need to handle this at the client level, that is the program that makes the request

Comment: My client applications is OpenLayers

Comment: can I convert the configuration in proxyhost to message displays to the user ?

Comment: The proxyhost probably doesn't understand enough of the protocol to provide meaningful errors.

Answer (score 4):

As explained at [OpenLayers load WFS vector layer: how to check whether all features are returned from server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21652/openlayers-load-wfs-vector-layer-how-to-check-whether-all-features-are-returned), you can set a callback on the read operation, and from that you can check whether there are any errors.