# zoomToExtent (getDataExtend) combined CQL filter, does not work

Tags: openlayers-2, cql-filter

I'm using openlayers 2.12 and geoserver 2.1.3.

I created a search functionality for a vector layer that contains points/lines/polygons. I used CQL that dynamically gets data from a form.

When I use `map.zoomToExtent(pins.getDataExtent());` does not work at all, instead it zooms 100% on an irrelevant place of the map. Never zooms to contains just the newly created features.

Map also contains other vector layers with no search functionality and a Google maps layer. All projections are `EPSG 900913`.

Check the following code. Form's "name" is a textfield, "era" is a dropdown and "borough" is  a dropdown containing string that will turn to `Bounds` , so map will zoom to a borough.

Search for : era OR name OR era+name with `zoomToExtent (getDataExtend)` on = zooms 100% at irrelevant place. I want this to zoom at new features.

Search for : era OR name OR era+name with `zoomToExtent (getDataExtend)` off = does not zoom, as it should be

Search for : era+borough OR name+borough OR era+name+borough with `zoomToExtent (getDataExtend)` on = zooms 100% at irrelevant place. I want this to zoom at new features.

Search for : era+borough OR name+borough OR era+name+borough with `zoomToExtent (getDataExtend)` off = zoom,at the borough as it should be.

The code...

```
//first, clear the layer
pins.removeFeatures(pins.features);
pins.refresh({force:true});

//split the chosen borough, to create bounds, so the map can zoom there
var binfo=document.getElementById("boroughselect").value;
if(binfo!=" "){
var split_binfo = binfo.split(",");
var bidchoosen=split_binfo[0];
var zoomTo=new OpenLayers.Bounds(split_binfo[1], split_binfo[2], split_binfo[3], split_binfo[4]).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
map.zoomToExtent(zoomTo);}

//create a filter using CQL
var filter_list = []

if (document.getElementById("eraselect").value != " ") {
    var filter_b = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
        property: 'p_era', 
        value: document.getElementById("eraselect").value
    });
    filter_list.push(filter_b);}

if (document.getElementById("nm").value != "") {
    var filter_c = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE,
        property: 'p_name', 
        value: document.getElementById("nm").value
    });
    filter_list.push(filter_c);}

//create the final filter,combining the above,  to search
var filter_final = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
    filters: filter_list});

//pass the filter to the layer
var prot =  new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
    url:  "http://localhost/geoserver/wfs",
    featureType: "pins",
    featureNS: "http://www.cultmap.gr",
    defaultFilter: filter_final});

var _CallBack = function(resp) {
    pins.addFeatures(resp.features)

var cb = pins.features.length;
if (cb == 0){
    document.getElementById("formMsgG").innerHTML = No results, please try again.";
            }};

var response = prot.read({callback: _CallBack});

pins.refresh({force:true});
map.zoomToExtent(pins.getDataExtent());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same issue has been well answered in [OpenLayers load WFS vector layer: how to check whether all features are returned from server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21652). But here is a quick answer, the reason is that by the time you call `pins.getDataExtent()` the wfs protocol has not finished reading all the features, so the `_CallBack` has not been executed. In your case you may zoom to layer's data extent after add features to the layer, i.e. in `_CallBack` function after this line:

```
pins.addFeatures(resp.features)
```

Comment: First of all I am happy that someone ansered. I thought my question is so big that nobody will anser. Second, thanks alot sir, it worked right away, by calling `pins.getDataExtend()` after `pins.addFeatures(resp.features)` in the `_Callback`. Thanks for helping and for your time